# .find finding empty cell

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have a VBA code that searches for a value in another workbook, in all sheets of it, and then writes yes or no in the source file. I use the .find argument inside a loop so it searches in all sheets, and this is inside another loop so it searches for multiple values. The searched value is set as a variable. Turns out that when I went to look in a sample if it was doing it right, sometimes it returns the address of an empty cell, for example: the searched value is 8 and it says that it found the value but when I look at the address of it, it is an empty cell, so in reality the find didn't really work.

Also, I set a variable using a value from the source file that needs to be the same value of a cell offset from the result, and if it is not, I made the code continue searching. When it finds this empty cells, it stops, I don't know why...

The code is something like this, I left some parts of it that are not useful.

```
dim NFE as range
dim searchedvalue as range
dim validation as range
dim sh as worksheet, wb as workbook

set searchedvalue = thisworkbook.worksheets (name).range
set validation = thisworkbook.worksheets (name).range
for each sh in wb.worksheets
set nfe = Workbooks(wbname).Sheets(sh.Name).Columns([column]).Find(searchedvalue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
if nfe.offset ().value = validation then
exit for
thisworkbook.range().value = "yes"
else
thisworkbook.range ().value = "no"
end if
next sh
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `searchedvalue` is a range not a value. Also why is that the same as `validation`?

Comment: @findwindow I'm not sure I understand... this is actually the result of some searching I made and even some questions here, I don't really know why it is set as range. Anyway, both validation and searchedvalue are values inside a specific cell on the source file.

Comment: You declared it as a range.... `dim searchedvalue as range` XD While you might have done research (laudable), you might not understand the code XD If you take a look, both variables are set to the same thing (`thisworkbook.worksheets (name).range`) XD

Comment: Posting "pseudo code" is worse than posting your *actual* code. "something like this" means I'm wasting time looking for details in there.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue. My code was missing a thisworkbook.sheets string when defining searchedvalue, so when it would set it, it would get an empty cell and that would give me the wrong result. Works fine now, thank you all for the help.